# PHP 5.3 constructor method

Tags: php, oop, composition

I am a Java/C# programmer who is trying to learn/finish a project in PHP.
Can anyone explain to me why "Composition" doesn't work in PHP 5.3 as one would expect from an object oriented language?

I have tried to research the issue, but due to term-confusion (making Google useless...) and bad documentation, I haven't been able to find anything useful yet.

```
<?php /*PHP VERSION 5.3.3*/

class MyClassOne
{
    public function myFunctionOne()
    {
        echo "<p> My Function One </p>";
    }
}

class MyClassTwo
{
    private $myClassOne;

    function __constructor() // WRONG WRONG WRONG - __construct() - and it works.
    {
        $this->myClassOne = new MyClassOne();
    }

    public function myFunctionTwo()
    {
        echo "<p> My Function Two </p>";
        $this->myClassOne->myFunctionOne(); // This crashes the "application"
    }

}


$myclassone = new MyClassOne();
$myclassone->myFunctionOne();
$myclasstwo = new MyClassTwo();
$myclasstwo->myFunctionTwo();


/*
Expectet result:
My Function One
My Function Two
My Function One

Real result:
My Function One
My Function Two
(application/runtime crash)
*/

?>
```

It will be highly appreciated if anyone can provide an explanation or show me the relevant documentation for this behavior.

Comment: You should be getting an error message returned. If you are not, change your error reporting and/or error display settings in php.ini.

Comment: See comments in the code.

Comment: Well, first off - there is no `construcor()` method. THere is `__construct`. Your second class never creates the object you expect. Reading the error message would tell you everything, but it might be that you turned errors off.

Comment: Thanks for the answers/input. I will never forget to use error_reporting(E_ALL) and the php log again... i miss my compiler...

Comment: Just as a side note: PHP 5.3.3(almost 4 years old) is  outdated. The entire 5.3 branch will be dropped in July 2014. Use Atleast php 5.4 or better 5.5 to get latest updates (including security updates, ofc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo.  Change `__constructor` to `__construct` and it will work correctly.

PHP constructors should be named `__construct()` as per [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: Well caught sir. I still can't get IntelliJ to autocomplete the function with $this->myClassOne-> , but the codes works as expected now. Thank you very much.